# Не запускается в фоне бот на pyTelegramBotAPI

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telebot

Код работает исправно, но не запускается в фоне, чтобы бот работал. Обычный эхо-бот.

```
import telebot
bot = telebot.TeleBot("Токен здесь есть", parse_mode=None)
@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Howdy, how are you doing?")
```

Без ошибки: Process finished with exit code 0

Answer (score 1):

Вы создали все условия для запуска бота: теперь он знает, что ему делать в определённом вами случае(при получении команд start и help отправлять приветственное сообщение). Вы забыли запустить бота, чтобы он ждал этих событий.

Чтобы ваш бот заработал нужно всего лишь добавить строчку:

```
bot.infinity_poling()
```